# Laravel 419 on post requests after upgrade from 5.4

Tags: laravel

Did an upgrade from 5.4 to 5.7, after that every ajax post request is 419 with:

```
    {message: "", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException",…}
exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException"
file: "pathto/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php"
line: 204
message: ""
trace: [{,…}, {file: "pathto/public_html/app/Exceptions/Handler.php", line: 47, function: "render",…},…]
0: {,…}
class: "Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler"
file: "pathto/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php"
function: "prepareException"
line: 176
type: "->"
```

Followed the upgrade instructions which especially mentioned about Cookie Serialization:

```
protected static $serialize = true;
```

Cleared cache, checked the file permissions are ok. Went down to 5.6, then to 5.5 laravel versions but no help. Changed the cookie name, tried incognito. Tried to even bypass all:

```
protected $except = [
      "*"
    ];
```

But no change. What on earth could go wrong here?

**Edit:**

Ajax call:

```
                var $_token = $('#token').val();
                var url = '/delete';

                $.ajax({
                    headers: {'X-XSRF-TOKEN': $_token},
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: ({data: data}), // set up earlier
                    success: function (data) {

                    }
                });
```

Controller:

```
public function delete(Request $request)
    {  
      $id = $request->input('data);
      Post::where('id', $id)->delete();
     }
```

Also tried with $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')

This gave me:

```
payload is invalid
```

id token is taken from:

```
    <?php
    $encrypter = app('Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter');
    $encrypted_token = $encrypter->encrypt(csrf_token());
    ?>
    <input id="token" type="hidden" value="{{$encrypted_token}}">
```

Comment: post your controller method

Comment: did you also `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @AshleyBrown every method worked perfectly in 5.4 but after upgrade they do not so I very much doubt this is in the controller. And yes I did composer dump-autoload, sadly no help there neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old topic but I just got back to it now and figured it out.

Reason was that I was passing: XSRF-Token in older Laravel instead of CSRF-Token, the never versions don't seem to work with XSRF anymore. Switched to CSRF and that fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

just add

```html
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

to your blade template

something like

```html
<form method="POST" action="/projects">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">

     <label for="title">Title</label>

     <input id="title" class="form-control" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Project Title" required  />

  </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">

          Create Project

       </button>


     </div>
  
</form>
```

Comment: I am passing the csrf token already to the call. Also not a form but based to click instead. I also tried with {{ csrf_field }} and getting that value to pass in ajax headers but that resulted into "payload is invalid"

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without your controller and the actual ajax call... but I've had similar problems with this 419 error.  There were two causes for me:

1) Failed token verification.  To check, add this to your ajax call:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
```

Though... your having tried to except everything should have allowed this through (assuming you had that line in the right place).

**EDIT**:  If you are passing your `X-XSRF-TOKEN` from JavaScript, decode it using `decodeURIComponent()`

2) It's possible that your controller is trying to render the view without all the information it needs.  Any chance you need to send a variable through to the view in the ajax controller function and it is missing?  I realize this worked before, but there were some big changes to 5.5 (including the way CSRF was handled as above).

3) Just a general error that I've had, but it might be possible that the data is not transferring in the same way as it did with 5.4.  Just check to see if the way the data is coming in to the controller is not error-ing out.  IE do a dump from the controller before it gets back to the view and see what your browser reports is transferring

Comment: Ok I see! Thank you for the answer. I added more info to question. Didn't pass anything directly to view in any of ajax calls. And controller, Even if I exit; straight in the first line in controller I'm getting that error.

Comment: Thanks for posting your ajax call.  I think I might have the answer to your problem see edit above.

Comment: Going to be a few days that I get to try this out again, but thanks! I'll give it a go then and update!